# Ckeditor unable to use percentages for image width and height

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to use percentages instead of a pixel for images when using CKEditor. I get the error "Width must be a number." when ever I try to add a % into either width or height.

Is there an easy way to disable the validation check or will I need to manually rewrite the validation code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not doable without modifying plugin code.

The image2 plugin you are asking about uses only pixels:

- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image2/dialogs/image2.js#L448
- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image2/dialogs/image2.js#L75-L83

Sure you could use below code on your HTML page to disable validation:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins : 'image2'
    image2_disableResizer : true
});

CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if (dialogName == 'image2') {

        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

        infoTab.get('width').validate = function() {
            return true; //more advanced validation rule should be used here
        }

        infoTab.get('height').validate = function() {
            return true; //more advanced validation rule should be used here
        }
    }
});
```

Please note however that image2 uses also the resizer which works in pixels and it could mess up your size in %. Even if you disable the resizer like in code snippet above, there is still a rule in plugin code which removes `%` :

- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image2/plugin.js#L952-L953
- https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/image2/plugin.js#L17
  and even if you do all that, you will probably get into few other obstacles.

To summarize: without changing plugin code you won't be able to use `%`

Comment: Alright, that's kind of what I figured. Do you know another option for displaying responsive images using CKeditor?

Comment: Well, you have three choices and all require work. You can either try rewriting the image2 plugin, searching for some third-party plugin which does what you want or you could try altering editor behavior like it has been shown here for example: https://gist.github.com/fabiomaggio/c2f4b84756cb4d82c0ae.